# command-t vim "Could not load C extension"

Tags: installation, vim, extension

When I hit \t to use the Command-T extension in VIM, I get the error

```
command-t.vim could not load the C extension
```

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this... any suggestions?

Thanks

---

I am using the git-repository installation method.
Here's what happens when I "rake make":

```
~/.vim/bundle/command-t$ rake make
(in /home/petef/.vim/bundle/command-t)
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:24:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from extconf.rb:24
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb...]
/home/petef/.vim/bundle/command-t/Rakefile:136
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pete, you must install ruby-dev package before invoke "rake make" command.

Answer (score 5):

Command-T requires a compiled C extension to work. Here's the relevant section from the [Command-T homepage](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) on how to compile the extension:

```
The C extension must also be then compiled; for instance, if Vimball installs
your plugin files in ~/.vim, then you would do this: 

  cd ~/.vim/ruby/command-t 
  ruby extconf.rb 
  make 

Note that Command-T requires a version of VIM with Ruby support enabled, and 
it must be compiled using the same version of Ruby that Vim itself links 
against. For more details see the documentation: 

    http://git.wincent.com/command-t.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/README.txt
```

Comment: I installed it with the git-repository method.  In my command-t directory, I don't see any extconf.rb file.  When I 'rake make' per the instructions, I have the same problem.

Comment: Did you get it working, Pete?

Just wandered thru this field myself -- you're probably missing the ruby-dev package on your system. Shout if you're still stuck; I'll walk you thru it.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that usually trips people up the most is that their Command-t has been compiled with a different version of Ruby than their Vim's version. In order do install Ruby and match the proper versions, you are going to want to install RVM and Ruby, install the correct version of Ruby, and do a `rake make` in the `~/.vim/bundle/Command-T` plugin directory.

[Here](http://www.justinbar.net/post/install-vim-with-ruby-support-and-command-t-plugin-on-ubuntu) is a step-by-step guide to install Command-t.